# A strange OSM tiles in Mapproxy

Tags: openstreetmap, wms, tiles, mapproxy

Could someone please help me with my issue? I try to use Mapproxy with OpenStreetMap server of tiles in order to get output WMS for my qgis client. Something like this:
...

```
sources: 
  arcgis_tms:
    type: tile
    url:  http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/%(tms_path)s.png
grids:
  arcgis_online:
    base: GLOBAL_MERCATOR
    num_levels: 18
    origin: nw
```

But I see something strange with my tiles(North and West are confused):http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5804/5372191.0/0_76c21_4563963e_orig

I change it to http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/%s/%s/%s.png and get many mistakes like:

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string, finally I add
>   supported_format: image/png but the problem remained.

Can someone explain how it works with tiles ( %(z)s/%(y)s/%(x)s.png ) ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the arcgis_online grid in your source configuration.
http://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/sources.html#grid

See also: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapproxy/2012-July/001123.html